# How to implement a "Remember Me" function in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, remember-me

What are the best practices to implement a "Remember Me" function in Rails 3 application ?

I store session information (session id + user id) in the database when user logs in, and I don't want to use any plugins at this moment.

Any pointers or code samples will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have been reading the Rails tutorial book and it has an implementation for Remember Me

You can check for some hints (The implementation may be different from yours)

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec:remember_me

Answer (score 8):

You can just set the expiration on a signed cookie to accomplish this.  (Signed cookies are tamper-proof just like the Rails-provided `session` cookie.)

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    ...
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email_address], params[:password])

    if params[:remember_me]
      cookies.signed[:user_id] = { value: user.id, expires: 2.weeks.from_now }
    else
      # expires at the end of the browser session
      cookies.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete :user_id
  end
end 

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def current_user
    User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id])
  end     
end
```

Comment: I'm surprised this approach isn't getting more attention.  I just killed a lot of time trying to do the remember_me token the way devise and others suggest doing it.  But cookies.signed is remarkably clean and simple in comparison.

Comment: There is a security issue with storing user_id in a signed cookie. The SignedCookieJar only signs the content of the cookie, not the name. This means that if you have the signed cookies first_name and user_id, someone can copy the value of the cookie first_name  and put it in user_id and the server will accept it. If you user input in a signed cookie than you're at risk.

Answer (score 3):

[Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com) has [an episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password) on achieving this as well as well as a great HOWTO on implementing those features [via BDD with RSpec and Capybara](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test).

> I store session information (session id + user id) in the database when user logs in

I believe that's one approach and the casts above does the same with cookies by issuing each `User` account a unique authentication token.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented remember_me (the below snippet is from my [example Rails app on authentication](https://github.com/maprihoda/primal_auth)):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :login_required, :only => [:new, :create]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @current_user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])

    if @current_user
      @current_user.track_on_login(request)

      if params[:remember_me]
        cookies[:remember_token] = { :value => @current_user.remember_token, :expires => 24.weeks.from_now }
      else
        cookies[:remember_token] = @current_user.remember_token
      end

      redirect_to dashboard_url, :notice => "Logged in successfully."
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login or password."
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.track_on_logout
    current_user.reset_remember_token_and_save  # can't rely on the 'save_current_user_if_dirty' after_filter here

    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    reset_session

    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You have been logged out."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example without salt:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protected

  def signin!(user_id)
    return unless user_id
    @current_user = User.find(user_id)
    self.session_user_id = @current_user.id
    self.permanent_user_id = @current_user.id if session[:accept_remember_me]
  end

  def signout!
    self.session_user_id = nil
    self.permanent_user_id = nil
    session[:accept_remember_me] = nil
    @current_user = nil
  end

  def remember_me
    session[:accept_remember_me] = true
  end

  private

  def permanent_user_id
    cookies.signed[:permanent_user_id]
  end

  def permanent_user_id= value
    cookies.permanent.signed[:permanent_user_id] = value
  end

  def session_user_id
    session[:user_id]
  end

  def session_user_id= value
    session[:user_id] = value
  end

end
```